# How to make post request with retrofit + moshi

Tags: android, kotlin, arraylist, retrofit2

I'm trying to make a post with retrofit and moshi but keep getting the error mess

> com.squareup.moshi.JsonDataException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at path $

I can't seem to understand why this is so. This is a sample of the json tested on postman:

```
{
"customerName": "Name",
"customerPhoneNo": "090000000",
"customerAddress": "Address",
"note": "Please",
"items" : [{
    "productUid": "5633e1f1-8b00-46de-b73e-43799245a4e8",
    "quantity" : "3"
},{
    "ProductUid": "fca3ffb1-0130-4e47-b499-721d046c1e32",
    "Quantity" : "5"
},
{
    "ProductUid": "6a7f3e24-03ff-408a-b67e-8530d411390c",
    "Quantity" : "2"
}]
}
```

My data classes are set up like so:

```
    @Parcelize
data class Order(
    val items: List<Item>?,
    val customerName: String,
    val customerPhoneNo: String,
    val customerAddress: String,
    val note: String
) : Parcelable
```

and

```
@Parcelize
data class Item(
    val productUid: String,
    var quantity: Int
) : Parcelable
```

Service utils look like:

```
interface ProductService {


    @Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
    @POST("/api/order/saveorder")
    suspend fun postProds(@Body order: Order
    ): Response<Order>

    @GET("/api/product/allproducts")
    suspend fun getProds(): Response<List<ProdsItem>>
}



private val moshi = Moshi.Builder()
    .add(KotlinJsonAdapterFactory())
    .build()

object Network {
    private val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
        .addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create(moshi)
            .asLenient()
        )
        .build()

    object ProdsApi {
        val retrofitService: ProductService by lazy {
            retrofit.create(ProductService::class.java)
        }
    }
}
```

The *sendOrder* function is set up like so:

```
suspend fun sendOrder(order: Order) {
        withContext(Dispatchers.Main){
            try {
                val orderResponse = Network.ProdsApi.retrofitService.postProds(
                    order   )
              
            }
            catch (e: Exception) {
               Timber.e(e)
            }
        }
    }
```

The GET request works perfectly.
Any help on this would be appreciated please.

Comment: Please write the complete error

Comment: That's all that is being printed

Answer (score 1):

Add to app/build.gradle

```
kapt "com.squareup.moshi:moshi-kotlin-codegen:1.13.0"
```

Refactor your data class

check the key in your item and replace with right one

```
 if productUid or ProductUid
 quantity or Quantity

@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
data class Item(
  @Json(name = "productUid")
  val productUid: String,
  @Json(name = "quantity")
  var quantity: String
 ) 

 @JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
 data class Order(
   @Json(name = "items")
   val items: List<Item>,
   @Json(name = "customerName")
   val customerName: String,
   @Json(name = "customerPhoneNo")
   val customerPhoneNo: String,
   @Json(name = "customerAddress")
   val customerAddress: String,
   @Json(name = "note")
   val note: String
  )
```

and try it again

Comment: Just did the refactor. Still have the same error

Comment: quantity is not int but string

I have edited the answer. try again

Comment: Also confirm your item values key values in item list
is it productUid or ProductUid
quantity or Quantity

then replace with right key and try again
{
    "productUid": "5633e1f1-8b00-46de-b73e-43799245a4e8",
    "quantity" : "3"
},{
    "ProductUid": "fca3ffb1-0130-4e47-b499-721d046c1e32",
    "Quantity" : "5"
}

Comment: Somehow Moshi is still throwing this exception even though it seems the request is getting through to the server (confirmed with a 200 response on HttpLoggingInterceptor and at the server side). Not sure if it's a bug from Moshi

Answer (score 1):

In your Item Data Class you are using quantity as an Int but if you see the Postman JSON response it is a String.

So your class should be like:

```
data class Item(
 @Json(name = "productUid")
 val productUid: String?,
 @Json(name = "quantity")
 var quantity: String
)
```

Also as I see the key in your JSON response are written in two different ways.
For example your "Product ID" is written as "productUid" in one of the object and is written as "ProductUid" in another object.

So your complete Item Data Class should more look like this :

```
data class Item(
    @Json(name = "productUid")
    val productUid: String?,
    @Json(name = "ProductUid")
    val productUid: String?,
    @Json(name = "quantity")
    val quantity: String?,
    @Json(name = "Quantity")
    val quantity: String?
)
```